# How to move an object in some defined angle?

Tags: javascript

"I am making a game in which I need to move an object to a target position. I am half the way but the ball has many defects like:
1) If you keep tx=ty then it works fine but when you change it, the object is displaced, but why?
2) If you keep the target behind the object, the object does not move, why?"

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var cx = 100; 
var cy = 100;
var r1 = 25;
var r2 = 50;
var a = 10;

var tx = 500;
var ty = 400;

function draw() {
    var vx = Math.cos(Math.atan2(ty, tx));
    var vy = Math.sin(Math.atan2(ty, tx));

    if(cx < tx && cy < ty){
        cx += vx + a;
        cy += vy + a;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    // target
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 179)";
    ctx.lineWidth = 20;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(tx, ty, r2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();

    // ball
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(179, 0, 0)";
    ctx.lineWidth = 20;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, r1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

Answer (score 0):

1 => Can you give an example in an edit to your question?
2 => This is probably because you check in your if statement this: `cx < tx && cy < ty`.
That means when `cx` and `cy` are both *smaller* then `tx` and `ty`.

Working snippet:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var cx = 100; 
var cy = 100;
var r1 = 25;
var r2 = 50;
var a = 0.5; // Made edit to 0.5 to move it slower

var tx = 500; // Made edit from t_x to tx
var ty = 400; // Made edit from t_y to ty

function draw() {
    var vx = Math.cos(Math.atan2(ty, tx));
    var vy = Math.sin(Math.atan2(ty, tx));

    if(cx < tx && cy < ty){
        cx += vx + a;
        cy += vy + a;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    // target
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 179)";
    ctx.lineWidth = 20;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(tx, ty, r2, 0, 2 * Math.PI); // Edit t_x and t_y to tx and ty
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();

    // ball
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(179, 0, 0)";
    ctx.lineWidth = 20;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, r1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: The problem was that the ball is not going to the centre of the target when tx is not equal to ty & I can't see the accelerating effect. But thank you for the solution for 2.